# Edit the date using DateTimePicker

Tags: winforms, formatting, format

I am able to edit month,date and year by using TAB or Arrow keys(MM-dd-yyyy). I have doubt is this possible to edit total date format at a time (not using tab key or any arrow keys).

Answer (score 2):

No, I don't think this is possible.  From [Using the DateTimePicker Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa231249%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)

> The DateTimePicker operates as a masked edit control for entering date and time values. Each part of the date or time is treated as a separate field within the edit portion of the control. As the user clicks on each field, it is highlighted and they can use the up and down arrow keys to increment or decrement the value of the field. The user can also type values directly into the control, where applicable.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! Is there another control to edit total date.

Comment: @KiranReddy You can try using a MaskedTextBox with a mask of "00-00-0000" or just a TextBox, and then validate the date in the `Validating` event.  Of course, you then lose the calendar drop down.  You could create your own custom control that does all that, but that would be a lot of work.  Maybe their is a 3rd party control you could look into, too.